# How to register all implementations of Generic interface in autofac?

Tags: c#, interface, autofac

I have created generic interface that suppose to map entities to view models and backwards. I have to make around 80 registrations in autofac configuration. Is it possible to register them as batch?
Here is the interface:

```
public interface ICommonMapper<TEntity, TModel, TKey>
    where TEntity : BaseEntity<TKey>
    where TModel : BaseEntityViewModel<TKey>
    where TKey : struct 
{
    TModel MapEntityToModel(TEntity entity);
    TModel MapEntityToModel(TEntity entity, TModel model);
    TEntity MapModelToEntity(TModel model);
    TEntity MapModelToEntity(TModel model, TEntity entity);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: you have 80 implementation of `ICommonMapper` ?

Comment: Around 80. 117 entity types... and around 80 of them are CRUDable

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You could use :

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
       .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(ICommonMapper<,,>));
```

Where `assemblies` is a collection of the assemblies where your types belong.

if you have a `PersonMapper` that inherits from `ICommonMapper<Person, PersonModel, Int32>`, *Autofac* will be able to resolve `ICommonMapper<Person, PersonModel, Int32>`

Comment: had to provide builder with IAssemblyFinder... worked.

Answer (score 9):

Don't need to make it complicated, you just simply need to register all the implementations of an interface as normal like below:

[image]

Then Autofac will automatically inject the implementations of that interface when it see the enumerable/array of the interface in a constructors like this.
[image]

I used this method and it works perfectly as I expect. Hope it helps. Cheers

Comment: There's a memory leak in that code as you capture a reference to an `IEnumerator<T>` but don't dispose of it - I assume you don't since your class doesn't implement `IDisposable`. Would you care explaining why you chose to go this way and not keep an `IEnumerable<T>` field?

Comment: Hi Mick, Thanks for your comment, I agree we need to dispose those instances, but it wasn't the focus of my answer here. I just wanted to give you guys an example of how to inject array of implementations of a particular interface into a specific instance using Autofac. For not keeping an IEnumerable<T> field because I just want to inject implementations of ICommandChainFeature into my CommandChain class :)

Comment: I get that, but why not have `private readonly IEnumerable<ICommandChainFeature> _features;` instead of the `IEnumerator<ICommandChainFeature>`?

Comment: I used IEnumerable because I want to use foreach loop when needed, this is a very basic knowledge. You can use List<T>, array of T, or whatever kind of list/array, Autofac would do the same thing for you. Hope it helps...If you find my answer helpful, you can give an upvote. Thanks

Comment: Nevermind. Your field is an enumerator, not an enumerable. My question is not related to the OP's question, so I'll stop here. Sorry for going off-topic, I was just curious.

Comment: 80 registrations one by one? ))) No! I'm too lazy! )))

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do that but with help of typeFinder:

```
var mappers = typeFinder.FindClassesOfType(typeof(ICommonMapper<,,>)).ToList();
        foreach (var mapper in mappers)
        {
            builder.RegisterType(mapper)
                .As(mapper.FindInterfaces((type, criteria) =>
                {
                    var isMatch = type.IsGenericType &&
                                  ((Type)criteria).IsAssignableFrom(type.GetGenericTypeDefinition());
                    return isMatch;
                }, typeof(ICommonMapper<,,>)))
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can tell autofac to register everything which implements an interface. I had to load a lot of things from several dlls so I did something like this, you should be able to adjust that to your own needs :

here's an example, you should be able to adjust that to your own needs :

```
foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
            {
                if (assembly.FullName.Contains("someNameYouCareAbout"))
                {
                    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
                   .AsImplementedInterfaces();
                }
            }
```